# can you explain?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function isIsogram(str){ 
  return !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str)
}
```

especially  the `!/(\w).*\1/i.test(str)` part

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212), the docs on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements), [What does this regex mean?](/q/22937618/4642212), the [regex tag wiki](/tags/regex/info), use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](//regex101.com/), read the [ES spec](//tc39.es/ecma262), the [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), and [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Test the regex on https://regex101.com/r/nkx56s/1 In the aside panel there's all you need to know. After you see what is matched, and since `.test()` returns a boolean, `!boolean` is just the inverse. If your function was named say `isNotIsogram` than the leading *Logical Not* operator `!` would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

An isogram is a word where every letter only appears at most once.

The regex `/(\w).*\1/i` can be split into 3 parts:

- `(\w)`: Find any "word character", i.e. alphanumeric character (or underscore) and save it as a group. This is the first group, so group 1.
- `.*`: Match any amount of characters, doesn't matter which *(except
  newlines)*
- `\1`: Match the first group again

The `/i` means the regex is case insensitive. The end result is that this RegEx checks whether it can find one letter (matched by `\w`) and can find the exact same letter again later (matched by `\1`).

The `regex.test(str)` just means "does this string match this regex?" while `!` inverts the result, so in the end, you have `return (not "is there a letter that appears twice?")`, aka an isogram.